# Dynamically adding colspan and removing the next td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3*3 table. I need to remove 3rd column if there is no content to display in it.In my js file I wrote something like below.

```
$('table tbody tr td').each(function () {
  if (tempHTML.indexOf("@E") !== -1) {    // true
    $(this).attr("colspan", 2);
    $(this).next("td").remove();         // removes extra td 
  }
});
```

`tempHtml` is my html, in my js file what should be the `this` to set colspan attribute?

Expected result is to increase the colspan and remove the next td and to have a 3*2 table. Please explain with detail as I'm new to js and html.

Comment: Can you post the html of the table as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody seems interested in answering you, and you asked how to realize your request in javascript, in spite of having presented code in jQuery, here is a solution:

```js
const MyTableBody = document.querySelector('#Table-3cols tbody')
  ,   BtRemC3     = document.querySelector('#Bt-Clean-col3')


BtRemC3.onclick=_=>
  {
  MyTableBody
    .querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)')
    .forEach(xTD=>
      {
      if (xTD.textContent==='')
        {
        let pTR = xTD.parentElement
        pTR.removeChild(xTD)
        pTR.cells[1].colSpan = 2
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey;  padding: .6em 1em}
thead { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<button id="Bt-Clean-col3">Remove empty Cols 3</button>

<table id="Table-3cols">
  <thead>
    <tr> <td>col 1</td> <td>col 2</td> <td>col 3</td> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td></td>   </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td></td>   </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

explanations for:  (arrow functions)

```
BtRemC3.onclick=_=>
  {
  MyTableBody
    .querySelectorAll(`td:nth-child(3)`)
    .forEach(xTD=>
      {
```

this is like :

```
BtRemC3.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  MyTableBody.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)').forEach( function(xTD)
  {
```

so, for the complete code this is :

```js
const MyTableBody = document.querySelector('#Table-3cols tbody')
  ,   BtRemC3     =  document.querySelector('#Bt-Clean-col3')
  ;
  
BtRemC3.addEventListener('click', function()
{
  MyTableBody.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)').forEach( function(xTD)
  {
    if (/@E/.test(xTD.textContent) ) // previously  (xTD.textContent==='')
    {
      let pTR = xTD.parentElement;
      pTR.removeChild(xTD);
      pTR.cells[1].colSpan = 2;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey;  padding: .6em 1em}
thead { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<button id="Bt-Clean-col3">Remove Cols 3 with '@E'</button>

<table id="Table-3cols">
  <thead>
    <tr> <td>col 1</td> <td>col 2</td> <td>col 3</td> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>blah blah blah@E  blah </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>blah blah@E  blah </td> </tr>
      <tr> <td>aa</td> <td>bb</td> <td>cc</td> </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I also changed the test about your `@E` value
regular expression to test if xTD.textContent contain '@E'

please read [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: You should edit the first sentence for an explanation of why this is working and how...

Comment: where is xTD defined?

Comment: `xTD` is the argument of the function (in the method .forEach) on this line 
`.forEach(xTD=>`  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#Accessing_the_matches

Comment: The above code gives me a syntax error. When I write the below line .forEach(xTD=>
      {
      if (xTD.textContent==='')
        {            I get error.

Comment: I modified it to below to fix the syntax error  cTableBody.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(3)').forEach(function (xTD) {
                                  if (xTD.textContent === '@E') {
                                      let pTR = xTD.parentElement

Comment: Now it complains saying xTD is undefined. How can I loop through each TD? how to make it realize that XTD is the value(td)?

Comment: Also how can I post code in the comment box more clearly?Is there any keyboard shortcut specific to the comments box?

Comment: give me a few minutes to show your points of syntax .. (do you have the correct parentheses for the beginning and the end?) and respect the parentheses too?

Comment: @user11809245  and please, when you got a error, you have to show the complete error message

Comment: "ReferenceError: xTD is not defined
    at eval (eval at srvOnSuccessCallback 
    at Object.success
    at fire (https://localhost/Scripts/jQuery/core/jquery-1.10.2.js:3062:30)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (https://localhost/Scripts/jQuery/core/jquery-1.10.2.js:3174:7)
    at done (https://localhost/Scripts/jQuery/core/jquery-1.10.2.js:8248:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (https://localhost/Scripts/jQuery/core/jquery-1.10.2.js:8791:8)"

Comment: In Javascript I know we need not to define the parameters before, but for me the control doesn't enter the if loop as xDT is not defined. How can I fix this?

Comment: my code is **javascript** not *jQuery* - **MyTableBody** (const) is a pure **javascript** element, not a *jQuery* one. It looks like you have mixed the 2 things, my code does not use jQuery

Comment: @user11809245  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Thank you very much Mister Jojo. You were right I mixed couple of things. Once I cleaned my code and implemented it like you showed, everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you need to do:

First, if you're using each, you should pass in the index and the value.  Then use the value when getting tempHTML, and doing your modifications to the HTML.

```js
$('table tbody tr td').each(function (i,f) {
    var tempHTML = $(f).text();

    if (tempHTML.indexOf("@E") !== -1) { //true
        $(f).attr("colspan", 2);
        $(f).next().remove();
    }
});
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey;  padding: .6em 1em}
thead { font-weight: bold }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AEC</td>
    <td>D@EF</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know where this css style came from. I didn't add it.

Comment: @MisterJojo I removed the CSS.  I don't know how it got in there.  I did test the rest of the code, and it works fine in Chrome.

Comment: The code the asker wrote says that if tmpHTML contains @E, then you set that TD to colspan=2, then delete the next column.  That's what my code does.

Comment: Ok, I finally understand what you're saying now.  The TD's need backslashes. Thanks for the heads up.  I thought you were talking about the script.

Comment: the PO ask : _"I need to remove 3rd column if there is no content to display in it."_ the `@E` come from nowhere..

Comment: @MisterJojo This is from the original code in the question:  if (tempHTML.indexOf("@E") !== -1)

Comment: I know that, but this is not the question.